# Ionic 2 LoadingController include custom content

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I want to use custom components inside the content option of the LoadingController of my Ionic 2 project but when the loading comes up the browser console shows me the message:

```
WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).
```

And the component is not showing, making test i realise that using any other TAG that was not standard HTML TAG throws this error, how i can use angular 2 security for bypass the error? what i whant is:

```
    this.loadingController.create({
        spinner: 'hide',
        content: `
        <div>
            <some-component></some-component>
            <h3>a message...</h3>
        </div>`
    })
```

Comment: Is your component included in your ng module?

Comment: Yes it was included.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you **cannot do that** according to [**the doc:**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/loading/LoadingController/#create)

> content   ----> string ---->  The HTML content for the loading indicator.

So you must pass the plain `string` HTML content like this:

```
content: `
      <div class="my-spinner">
        <div class="my-spinner-box"></div>
      </div>`,
```

Comment: I know but when i include an SVG that uses my component TAG the error comes also, so how i can include an SVG animated using CSS classes?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I am trying to add an ion-icon that is getting stripped as well.

Comment: @diff, sadly i don't have time for this for now, but when i find a solution i will post it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
//----------imports----------
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

//----------variables----------
safeHtml: any;

//----------constructor----------
constructor(public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer)

//----------your function----------
let svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox...whatever..</svg>';
// you can also add text BEFORE sanitizing
let html = svg + '<div class="loadingText">' + this.translate.instant('common.Loading') + '</div>';

this.safeHtml = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);

var loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    spinner: 'hide',
    content: this.safeHtml
});
loading.present();
```